# Simplify delivery options on magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have a magento shop with 3 different delivery options. Non of them are related to the destination. We only allow shipping in one country and in this country the rate for shipping is always the same. So therefore I don't need to ask my customers for their ZIP/Country to calculate the delivery costs. I only want to give them the three options to select - and nothing more.

How can I disable this "estimated delivery costs"-module without disabling the whole "choose your delivery"-thing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, what may be helpful, is the Auto Shipping module in the Magento Connect, it will automatically select the best shipping option. That way the customer will see the grand total including the shipping.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sounds good. Does it work without the "estimated delivery costs"-formular? Than I would like to combine your answer and the one from @Nikitas

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the **estimated delivery costs** that exists in `index.php/checkout/cart/`, it does not force the customer to insert his zip code. As i see in my shop it's optional. Of course if the customer type a zip code then it can change the shipping costs.

If this is the case then you can just disappear it...

In your CSS file:

```
.cart .shipping {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. The problem is that the I want to "calculate" the grand total including the shipping costs.